# SQL: How can I Parse firstname, lastname and title from fullname?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a column named `Employee name` in table 1

```
Example: Mr.FirstName LastName
```

and so on with various titles but there are employee names without the title in the same column.I am about to split the single column and do an insert in the new table (table 2) with three different columns like FirstName, LastName and Title.So while doing an insert into the new table I am not able to split the employee column name like I mentioned.Any help will be really appreciated I started with LINQ so I am not aware of much SQL functions.

Update : Sample data

[image]

Comment: Post up some sample data (more than one row, with the variations you mention), we can imagine it, but it will help if we can see it.

Comment: You should read [this](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). You can assume many things about names, most of those assumptions will be incorrect, making parsing near impossible.

Comment: The reason you are not finding an exact solution to this is because there really is no one-size-fits-all solution. Parsing names in SQL is always a mess with a thousand edge cases and lots of code to catch as much of the garbage as possible. If your data is greater than a few hundred records and sufficiently varied in format then it's unlikely that you will build a 100% solution. It's only exacerbated in SQL Server since there isn't any super-great parsing functions built in. It would be nice if they tossed a `strtok()` into one of their releases.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Yea we made a mess now trying to fix that.

Comment: @Leonidas199x  you can find the sample data here http://prntscr.com/gyy631

Comment: @JNevill True this database was designed previously by someone now it's me who has to come up with a fix to avoid the same problem again in future.

Comment: @MatSnow updated with a sample data screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one example.

```
DECLARE @name varchar(100) = 'Mr.FirstName LastName'

SELECT
LEFT(@name, CHARINDEX('.', @name)) AS Title,
SUBSTRING(@name, CHARINDEX('.', @name)+1, CHARINDEX(' ', @name)-CHARINDEX('.', @name)) AS FirstName,
SUBSTRING(@name, CHARINDEX(' ', @name)+1, 1000) AS LastName
```

It takes...

- the left part till the `.` as Title.
- everything after the `.` until the first `space` as FirstName
- everything after the first `space` as LastName

Note: There's no check for errors, if the name does not fit into this pattern.

Comment: Thanks made it work with some changes.The employee names of one client are the one's with title attached so i have given that as condition like @clientid in my select case statement to check for the rest i will just separate first and last name.Thanks all of you :)

Answer (score 1):

For the simplest case you specified in the question the following query should work

```
  SELECT *,
  SUBSTRING(Employee_name, 0, CHARINDEX('.', Employee_name)) AS Title,
  SUBSTRING(Employee_name, 
            CHARINDEX('.', Employee_name)+1,
            CHARINDEX(' ', Employee_name)) AS FirstName,
  SUBSTRING(Employee_name, 
            CHARINDEX(' ', Employee_name)+1,
            LEN(Employee_name)) AS LastName         
FROM Employee;
```

Comment: Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function